# Is saving uploaded filles in folder in the server a Good practice?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, google-cloud-firestore, azure-storage

Hey guys I'm begginer and asking if i could save uploaded files in a folder in the server and then save a path in the database

Note that I'm building a short video sharing app

Comment: I don't think there is any "right" answer to that question as the requirements are very vague.
In principle yes, you can store the paths in a database and stream the files back and forth. I think you'd need a fair bit of bandwidth and a lot of space if you're sharing videos though.
You may also wanted to consider data protection issues and the like as well.

Comment: I would expand on this question - you tagged all the cloud providers. In general yes you would store your file on say S3/cloudfront and save the path in your database. If by server you mean express then probably not as it's not going to be practical/cheap to store a lot of data though there is nothing inherently wrong with that as long as the server can stream/deliver appropriately.  Other considerations are that these cloud provides provide excellent streaming capabilities - check out https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/video-on-demand-on-aws/ for ex

Comment: @cyberwombat thanks for your reply yes by server i mean express but why it's not cheap can you pls explain it in More details

Comment: It's a generalization that may not always be true but if you intend to store a lot of data then using services such as S3 that aim to provide this at a reasonable cost vs say asking Heroku to give you lots of disk space is often cheaper.  Now as @BWG mentioned there is the additional consideration of protecting access to the data - something that is generally easier to do with AWS services that have it already built in so to speak. But since you are storing URL in db you can migrate later too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I can tell you from my personal experience + research.
**You should definitely put videos in a server and store the URL in the DB.**
Make sure you use a Compression Library inside your app to compress videos before uploading! Think of what's app and messenger, they compress before uploading.

When Retrieving Said videos, store them in the App Cache and try to clear the cache when the video is out of scope or not in use. An App like this requires multithreading for optimal performance. I know that there is a lot to take in but try to experiment, and you'll understand why these concepts are important.

For images, it may vary. I'm mentioning pictures because you may have thumbnails, etc. If they are small images and you're able to compress them you can store them as a Blob in your SQL DB however most people wouldn't recommend it.